# How to create service accounts in Snowflake

Tags: service, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, account, service-accounts, snowflake-schema

How can a service account be created in snowflake?
What parameters of a user can tell whether an account is a service account or not in snowflake?

Comment: You may look at the following article which details how the service account is used in Snowflake and how to secure them :
The following 3 blog articles would give details on this as : 
https://www.snowflake.com/blog/snowflake-service-account-security-part-3

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use a standard naming convention for service users and create these users so that they utilize key pair authentication using the RSA_PUBLIC_KEY parameter.